# How to send list of objects on retrofit

Tags: android

I need to send list of below objects on retrofit , but always I receive error , your body is null

```
{
  "height": "20",
  "weight": "40",
  "unit": "kg"
}
```

```
GetDataService service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetDataService.class);
        Call<ResponseBody> call = service.getAllPhotos("");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                Log.v("SUCCESS", response.body() + " ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to create your models use [click here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Your model will be like this

```
public class User {

@SerializedName("height")
@Expose
private String height;
@SerializedName("weight")
@Expose
private String weight;
@SerializedName("unit")
@Expose
private String unit;

public String getHeight() {
return height;
}

public void setHeight(String height) {
this.height = height;
}

public String getWeight() {
return weight;
}

public void setWeight(String weight) {
this.weight = weight;
}

public String getUnit() {
return unit;
}

public void setUnit(String unit) {
this.unit = unit;
}

}
```

On your API interface create this method

```
 @POST("/service name for example register")
    Call<ResponseBody> postUsers(@Body List<User> userRequest);
```

On Main Activity use below code

```
 public void postUsers(List<Users> userRequest) {
            GetDataService service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetDataService.class);
            Call<ResponseBody> call = service.postUsers(userRequest);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    Log.v("SUCCESS", response.body() + " ");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
```