# Java send nested data to server using retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I want to send data to server in this format to my server. This is the body my postman returns

```
{
    "name": "Passenger 1",
    "age": 22,
    "gender": "male",
    "citizen": "35-01-02434",
    "secondname": "",
    "secondphone": "",
    "transportation_id": 1,
    "date": "2022-10-12",
    "departure_time": "09:00:00",
    "arrival_time": "",
    "from": 1,
    "to": 2,
    "type": "bus",
    "seats": [
        {
            "seat_type": "leftB",
            "seat_number": "5",
            "type": "bus"
        },
        {
            "seat_type": "leftB",
            "seat_number": "6",
            "type": "bus"
        }
    ]
}
```

meaning i have to send this information to server but i am stuck at one point that is i do not know how to send seats data need some help.

by far what i have done was this

```
@POST("bookinglogs")
    Observable<BookingResponse>bookSeat(@Query("name") String name, @Query("age") int age, @Query("gender") String gender, @Query("citizen") String citizen, @Query("secondname")String secondName, @Query("secondphone") String secondPhone, @Query("transportation_id") int transportationId, @Query("date") String date, @Query("departure_time") String depatureTime, @Query("arrival_time")String arrivalTime, @Query("from") int from, @Query("to") int to, @Query("type") String type, @Header("Authorization") String authToken, @Header("Accept") String value);
```

but i have no idea how to send that seats data to server i have information of seats in list of array string like i have list of seat type in string and seat number in list of string also need some help thanks.

Comment: Don't send every query for each field like this, you should send a json object with `@Body`. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57989722/3682565)

Comment: You must first generate the jsonObject for your request before passing it on to the @Body.

Answer (score 1):

To send nested data with retrofit first have you to make a different model class for that nested in your case it is seats

seats is array type how do I know because of `[]` in your response.

so far we know that seats is array but what type of array ? so if you look at seats array's object you see this -

```
{
  "seat_type": "leftB",
  "seat_number": "5",
  "type": "bus"
}
```

so we just need create model class that matches that object properties like this

**Create a class name - `SeatModel.java` or `Seat.java`**

```
public class Seat {
    private String seat_type, seat_number, type;

    public Seat(String seat_type, String seat_number, String type) {
        this.seat_type = seat_type;
        this.seat_number = seat_number;
        this.type = type;
    }

    // getter and setters
}
```

now we have seat that represent object of response type but we need it in array so we can do something like this -

we can use `ArrayList` or `List`.

**Create your main model class which represent your whole request** name it `DataModel.java` or whatever you think will suite

so in this model I have added your whole type of request data so you can use this -

```
public class DataModel {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String gender, citizen, secondname, secondphone;
    private int transportation_id;
    private String date, departure_time, arrival_time;
    private int from, to;
    private String type;
    private ArrayList<Seat> seats; // name should same as your response's seats

    // make sure to create constructor from above variables
    // make sure to also create getters and setters
}
```

---

You are using `@Query("name")` which is basically sending data as query like

```
https://yourdomain.com/bookinglogs?name=jhon
```

so instead of using `@Query()` for every properties use that `DataModel` and send as a `@Body`

Do something like this :

```
@POST("bookinglogs")
Observable<BookingResponse>bookSeat(@Body DataModel bookingData, @Header("Authorization") String authToken, @Header("Accept") String value);
```

I hope you get it :)